# Are NAT rules not subjected to firewall / policy group rules on an ASA?

Tags: cisco-asa

Have an existing ASA that has a config I inherited.  Looking at the firewall I do not see a rule that allows traffic of a certain pattern to traverse the firewall.  I do see the pattern applied for NAT'ing reasons and I'm curious, if you have a NAT policy defined, is that traffic able to bypass the firewall?

For example, I have one access list defined as:

`access-list policy-nat extended permit udp object-group MY_OBJ any eq snmp`

and another as

`access-list firewall-list extended permit udp host 1.2.3.4 host 6.7.8.9 eq snmp`

Both ACL's are applied to the same interface as such:

`nat (my-int) 22 access-list policy-nat
access-group firewall-list in interface my-int`

Will any traffic patterns that conform to the NAT rules bypass the access-group entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nope, traffic that matches a NAT rule will not bypass the firewall rules.

Rules are applied in the following order:

- Incoming ACL on the incoming interface
- NAT rules
- Outgoing ACL on the outbound interface

You may find a graphic representation of the process here:
http://www.tunnelsup.com/cisco-asa-order-of-operation

Hope that helps!

Comment: FYI.  This changes in 8.3+.  NAT is processed before ACLs.